# Store PHP session_id in MySQL for AJAX authorization?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, authorization, sessionid

Not too clear on how to authorize PHP AJAX calls with session_id or against any $_SESSION variables actually.

Should it be stored in the database upon login and referenced against a $_SESSION storage on each AJAX call?

I know these subjects have probably been discussed ad infinitum, but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance!

**Revelation**

Wow, so authorization is limited to whether or not there's a session?  Scary.  Makes me wonder if that's all that .net's web.config's deny="?" is doing.  Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Ajax Auth? Then you need to figure out if the session does exists, then depending on this respond you'll send `JSON` respond back to `javascript`. Then on each request you'd send `http` request to see if this has proper value to display as "authorized". It's not that complex. You don't need `session_id()` for that. Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is always there because session data is server-side. As long as they have the cookie that grants them that session, they are considered an authorized user.

In the beginning of the file being called through AJAX, just do something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    exit;
}

?>
```

Nothing will be executed beyond that point unless they have an active session.

You can prevent people from accessing your AJAX files directly too, just add this:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) OR ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest')) {
    exit;
}

?>
```

Someone could still get around that, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: first, thank-you for your help.  but isn't it more than just an active session?  don't we at least need to prevent hijacking by somehow knowing who we're talking to?  i don't understand the point of the session_id otherwise.

Comment: Sessions are stored server-side, but the browser contains a cookie that authorizes them to that session. If you only allow an active session to be created by a valid user, then there would never be an invalid session. Session data can't be manipulated by the user.

Comment: where i'm getting lost is how to authorize ajax calls to php files to logged in users only.  how does php know that session_id X is connected to user Y.  it seems like I'm missing a step to make sure that session_id X isn't attributed to user Z, or any other user for that matter.  again, thank you

Comment: The second piece of code in my post restricts access to only AJAX requests. The first piece of code checks for a session, and if they are not logged in, the AJAX request fails. Once you verify that they have a session ID, which should be their primary key in your database, you use it to restrict what they can or can't do during the AJAX call: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='John' WHERE id='$_SESSION[id]' LIMIT 1")

Comment: interesting.  so sessions by themselves are not enough?  there's no way to cross check with them alone?  it is correct/best practice to store the session_id into the database to make sure that the user matches the id?  tyvm

Comment: You have it backwards. You take a field in your database (such as "id" and/or "email") and use that to create their session, which can then be used to securely identify them when they visit a page or perform an action(even AJAX calls). "id" would be an auto incrementing number in your database, and "email" would be a field in your database that is set when they first signup.

Comment: isn't that a little too static?  what happens if somebody finds out about those associations?  why wouldn't you want to set a random session_id, put it in the db, and if the user and session_id don't match, block?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17425/discussion-between-brian-holt-and-joe-coder-guy)